# SWRevealViewController navigation bar right button item

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm using the SWRevealViewController library to use on my app as a left slide menu;

github link: [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)

I've downloaded the following project example
[Appcoda project example](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/)
and I've embedded the menu controller to a navigation controller so I can add items to the bar button , but I can't see the right bar button item that I've added (+ sign as example of ADD)

I've tried to change the menu controller width, but everything went wrong , do you know a way to short the side menu width so I can see the right bar button item added?

In the following image the + sigh stays under the left (main) controller.

I'm new to this kind of things :)

Thanks in advance

[image: Example]

Comment: It is actually under the MainViewController. Better not to use a navigation bar and right-bar button for this! Use a uibutton similar to add button and place it at the required position!

Comment: Hmm... I'll try that one and I'll say something later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like the code below and set x value according to your position in `cgrectmake`

```
 UIButton *PlusBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,44,44)];
    PlusBtn.tag = 654;
    [PlusBtn setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(14, 14, 16, 16)];
    [PlusBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_icon1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [PlusBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(ShowLeft) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    PlusBtn.enabled = NO;

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:PlusBtn];
```

Comment: This sounds good. I'll try it out and I'll leave feedback then

Comment: ya sure u can try this

Answer (score 2):

In Storyboard you set the UiViewController's size to be freeform instead of Inferred under Attributes Inspector, then under Size Inspector you set the width of the ViewController according the the size that the button shows.[image][image]